# Property reflection inside of a LINQ query doesn't behave as expected

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

Given the following lines of code in C#:

```
var testvalue = result[0]
  .GetType()
  .GetProperty(propertyNameToFilterOn)
  .GetValue(result[0], null);

var test = result
  .Where(x => x
      .GetType()
      .GetProperty(propertyNameToFilterOn)
     ?.GetValue(x, null) == "46ee6799-2bed-4a7a-93f8-0839affbd218")
  .ToList();
```

result obviously contains a collection of objects. The first line gives me a value (46ee6799-2bed-4a7a-93f8-0839affbd218). However, the second line returns 0 objects in the list. The first line confirms that the first object in the collection does have the value I'm filtering on in the second line, while the second line tells me that no objects in the collection has that value on the property I'm checking. Can someone explain why this does not work? And potentially provide an alternative?

Comment: What is the return type of the property? `GetValue` will return an `object` so I'm guessing that you're comparing two string instances that have the same value but are not the same instance.

Comment: Is the property string or Guid? If one or the other, Guid != string when compared.

Comment: Try using `Equals()` instead of `==` if my above theory is correct.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you are **actually** trying to do?

Comment: the return type of the property is unknown. It's a generic T. But when I test I test with a specific type. And in this case the property is a string guid (but it could be anything that goes into an azure table entity in theory).

Comment: @user1339253 That is the actual question there. Show the generic function. You could construct a dynamic linq expression to be used in the Where call.

Comment: @Nkosi These lines are basically just to debug why it didn't work. Replacing with .equals seems to have done the job. If you are interested, though, this is the (now working) lines of code: https://pastebin.com/Cu4FS24v

Comment: @DStanley You were correct :) Feel free to answer the question and I'll approve your answer

Comment: @user1339253 Dmitry took care of it.

Comment: @user1339253 looking at the pastebin I am curious about that filter. So in I understand this correctly the filtered property will be equal to the partition key?

Comment: @user1339253 understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `?.GetValue(x, null)` returns instance of `object`, when you compare it with `"46ee6799-2bed-4a7a-93f8-0839affbd218"` you compare **references**, not **values**:

```
string st = "46ee6799-2bed-4a7a-93f8-0839affbd218";

// Some manipulations (we don't want the compiler to intern strings)
object o = (st + " ").Trim();

Console.WriteLine(o == st ? "Equal" : "Not Equal");
Console.WriteLine(string.Equals(o, st) ? "Equal" : "Not Equal");
```

**Outcome:**

```
Not Equal
Equal
```

Use `string.Equals` instead of `==` in order to compare *values*:

```
var test = result
  .Where(x => string.Equals(x
      .GetType()
      .GetProperty(propertyNameToFilterOn)
     ?.GetValue(x, null), "46ee6799-2bed-4a7a-93f8-0839affbd218"))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: If the original person who answered the question doesn't post an answer in a while I'll approve this.